# Setting Correct Liquidty Lock Value

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I am looking to deploy a test contract and want to know what values i should enter to set the liquidity lock to either 7 days and 30 days. I need to input a numerical value in uint256 format. Can someone please help. Thank You

```
function lock(uint256 time) public virtual onlyOwner {
    _previousOwner = _owner;
    _owner = address(0);
    _lockTime = now + time;
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
}

function unlock() public virtual {
    require(_previousOwner == msg.sender, "You can't unlock");
    require(now > _lockTime , "Contract is locked");
    emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, _previousOwner);
    _owner = _previousOwner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So on the blockchain, time is a very difficult thing to capture as every node (Computer) can have a different time. And with this I mean split second differences. So how we do it on the blockchain is we use a certain block height/block number and its estimated epoch time.

We can use this for time, because we have a rough estimate on how long it will take each block to be mined and this is something most blocks have consensus on.

You can convert "normal time" to epoch time here:
https://www.epochconverter.com/

Hope this helps